# Mongoose Indexing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am having problems with indexing in Mongoose. I have an employeeId field which is unique. When I create a employee document it creates a index "employeeId_1" and also I find there is a Index "*id*". I would imagine it should be "_id". Could someone walk over what I am doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId = mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId;

var eContactSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    contacttype:{type: Number},
    name:{type: String, required:true},
    phone:{type: String, trim: true},
    mail1:{type: String, trim: true},
    mail2:{type: String, trim: true},
    city:{type: String, trim: true},
    state:{type: String, trim: true},
    zip:{type: String, trim: true}
})

var eCourseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    course:{type: ObjectId, required:true, unique: true},
    title:{type: String},
    notes:{type: String, trim:true},
    expire:{type: Date},
    deleted: {type: Boolean, default: false}
})

var eAppSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    appName:{type: String, required: true, trim: true},
    view:{type: Boolean, default: false},
    create:{type: Boolean,default: false},
    edit:{type: Boolean,default: false},
    del:{type: Boolean,default: false}
})

var employeesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstName:{type: String, trim:true, required:true},
    lastName:{type: String, trim:true, required:true},
    employeeId: {type: String, trim:true, required:true, unique: true},
    active: {type: Boolean, default: true},
    admin: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    title: {type: String, trim:true},
    pin:{type:String, trim: true},
    contacts:[eContactSchema],
    courses:[eCourseSchema],
    apps:[eAppSchema]
})

module.exports = db.model('employees', employeesSchema,'employees');
```

Here is how I create the document.

```
       exports.addEmployee = function (data, callback) {
    employees.create(data, function (err) { callback(err) });
};
```

Here is the getIndex results. For some reason I cannot recreate the issue but along with this there will be another index with the name employeeId_1. It will trow an duplicate error on key employeeId_1.

```
[
  {
    "v": 1,
    "key": {
      "_id":1
    },
    "ns": "Management.employees",
    "name": "_id_"
  }
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Can you edit your question to include the `db.employees.getIndexes()` output from the shell and what you think is wrong about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The _id field is created automatically for every document created. You **can not** change its name or remove it.

**employeesSchema will has 2 primary keys:**

- employee._id
- employee.employeeId

that is why you see two index in your mongoose

---

Edit:

After create model, we must wait for index event before create document

```
User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

User.on('index', function () {
   new User({}).save();
   new User({}).save();
   new User({}).save();
   new User({}).save();
})
```

If you do not wait for index event, the index may not be created (and you will not see any warning from mongoose about it)

I have report this to mongoose and get reply on this issue:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1745

Comment: Now I'm not even getting the second index employeeId

Comment: if on('index') is your problem, you can make 2 files, install.js for creating db models, and app.js for adding documents, then run separately in terminal.